# Defining UTF-16BE strings in C++

Tags: c++, utf-16, endianness

I need to define unicode string that would look like so:

```
const char SOME_STRING[] = { 0, 5, 0, 'M', 0, 'y', 0, 'S', 0, 't', 0, 'r' };
```

This is UTF-16BE string prepended with big endian short containing length, it's used in java and that's what I need it for. Is there better/cleaner way to declare it than typing every character separately?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wchar_t` instead, converting to bytes on demand, for example:

```
const wchar_t some_string[] = L"\x05MyStr";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= some_string[0]; i++)
        printf("%d %d ", some_string[i] >> 8, some_string[i] & 0xFF);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Why would it not work on a big-endian platform? It gets a `wchar_t` and shifts or masks the value. That's not sensitive to endianness.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ do not define how the endian nature of the platform they are running on works. Therefore, there is no way within the language themselves to declare a sequence of 16-bit values to be "big endian".

What you have to do is get the string in the platform native endian. Then do byte swapping if the endian-ness of the platform is not big endian. You can store the byte-swapped version in a `std::vector` or some such.